# How to assign shards in AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

[image]

But because I'm hosting on AWS I'm not allowed to call `/_settings` or `/_cluster` so how can I assign those shards?

The error I'm getting when I `POST` to `/_cluster`:

```
{
  "Message": "Your request: '/_cluster' is not allowed."
}
```

Comment: It's likely that you have configured one replica per primary shard and since you have only one node, the replicas cannot be assigned.

Comment: @Val My understanding of this is limited but how do I "fix" this? What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: How did you create your index?

Comment: @Val `PUT /my-index` with `number_of_shards: 1` (plus an analysis and mappings that I can include if needed).

Comment: Why the -1 anonymous user?

Comment: People sometimes downvote, but don't have the balls to tell you why ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, one replica shard is created per primary shard and since you have only one node, the replicas cannot be assigned.

You simply need to pass `number_of_replicas:0` when you create your index

```
PUT /my-index
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

If you later want to increase the number of replica shards because you add new nodes, you can do it like this:

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I were to increase the number of shards what would be the process? (I swear I've read up about how shards/nodes/replicas work but it's very overwhelming imo)

Comment: Once an index is created you cannot increase the number of primary shards (in your case 1), you'll only be able to increase the number of replica shards, which you usually do if you add new nodes to scale horizontally

Comment: I suspect that I need to recreate my ES instance. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can simply run the second command above (with replica:0) to remove the replicas and the unassigned shards will disappear

Comment: Oh I thought I didn't have access to the `/_settings` in AWS method but it seems like I do. I ran the query and it stills says Yellow with 6 unassigned shards.

Comment: You need to do it on each of your indices. Apparently, you have several

Comment: Sweet. Green across the board! Thanks! :)

Comment: Awesome !! Glad we made it!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provide additional information about your system and requirements but I'll assume that:

1 ) You don't want to change the number of shards (not recommended).

2 ) You want that your cluster status to be green.

So it seems that you need to allocate more nodes to your domain.

Consider **increasing the number of master nodes to 3** and make sure you split them to 3 availability zones as can be seen in the UI console below:

[image]

Check the allocation with:

```
$ curl -XGET ES_Endpoint/_cat/allocation?v
```

And you should see that your 8 primary shards are being allocated evenly between the master nodes:

```
shards   disk.indices disk.used disk.avail   disk.total     disk.percent host        ip      node
     3       16.8mb    69.2mb      9.7gb      9.8gb            0        x.x.x.x   x.x.x.x   98da03fa1
     3       11.3mb    63.7mb      9.7gb      9.8gb            0        x.x.x.x   x.x.x.x   aea0f9c9
     2       18.2mb    70.6mb      9.7gb      9.8gb            0        x.x.x.x   x.x.x.x   af7fe965
```

---

I would  also recommend reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-dedicatedmasternodes.html) article from AWS:

> We recommend that you add three dedicated master nodes to each
> production Amazon ES domain. Never choose an even number of dedicated
> master nodes.
>
> 1 ) One dedicated master node means that you have no backup in the
> event of a failure.
>
> 2 ) Two dedicated master nodes means that your cluster does not have
> the necessary quorum of nodes to elect a new master node in the event
> of a failure.
>
> A quorum is the number of dedicated master nodes / 2 + 1 (rounded down
> to the nearest whole number), which Amazon ES sets to
> discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes when you create your domain.
>
> In this case, 2 / 2 + 1 = 2. Because one dedicated master node has
> failed and only one backup exists, the cluster doesn't have a quorum
> and can't elect a new master.
>
> 3 ) Three dedicated master nodes, the recommended number, provides two
> backup nodes in the event of a master node failure and the necessary
> quorum (2) to elect a new master.
>
> 4 ) Four dedicated master nodes are no better than three and can cause
> issues if you use multiple Availability Zones.
>
> If one master node fails, you have the quorum (3) to elect a new
> master. If two nodes fail, you lose that quorum, just as you do with
> three dedicated master nodes.
>
> In a three Availability Zone configuration, two AZs have one dedicated
> master node, and one AZ has two. If that AZ experiences a disruption,
> the remaining two AZs don't have the necessary quorum (3) to elect a
> new master.
>
> 5 ) Having five dedicated master nodes works as well as three and
> allows you to lose two nodes while maintaining a quorum. But because
> only one dedicated master node is active at any given time, this
> configuration means paying for four idle nodes. Many users find this
> level of failover protection excessive.